# How to .append() an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-physics

I'm making a simple game in javascript and I would like to `.append()` a box. To serve as a bullet. But I'm stuck. This is what I have

```
var existingdiv1 = document.getElementById('bullet');
```

and

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $("div").append([existingdiv1]); 
});
```

It wont create additional "divs" when I press the button "#test".

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212), but this is a special case where you use the “Array of Node” function signature of `append`. It works the same way, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to select the existing div (I guess this is the bullet?). Then append it.

Here's and example:
[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnwCB/1/)

**Javascript:**

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#appendToThis").append($('#bullet').html()); 
});
```

**Html:**

```
<input id="test" type="button" value="click" />
<div id="appendToThis"></div>

<div id="bullet"><div>BANG</div></div>
```

You will see the word "bang" be appended everytime you click. You can remove it by using the empty() method on the test div.

Comment: Note that it is better to use `.clone` to duplicate an element, instead of `.html`, since the browser does not have to convert the DOM element to HTML and back again.

Comment: I would also recommend to use `.on` as well.

Comment: If i would like to ad an animation to the appended item, will I put the animation inside the $("#test").click(function() or outside?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to add a new div to the existing div, so your code has been reversed the append order. and you need wrap the existing div by `$('#bullet')`
Try this

```
$('#bullet').append('<div></div>');
```

Comment: That's an interesting point. This could indeed be what the OP wants. The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`.append` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned).

It seems like you want to [clone *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element first:

```
$("div").append($(existingdiv1).clone());
// or simpler
$("div").append($('#bullet').clone());
```

Note though that if you have multiple `div` elements on your page, `$("div")` will select all of them and the element you pass to `.append` will cloned automatically (as stated in the documentation).
You should append the element only to a single div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $("#appendToThis").append($('#bullet').clone()); 
});
```